# How to obtain a confidence interval for the difference in two proportions in Stata

Tags: statistics, stata

I would like to obtain a confidence interval for the difference in two proportions.

For example

```
webuse highschool
tab race sex, col chi2


  1=white, |
  2=black, |   1=male, 2=female
   3=other |      male     female |     Total
-----------+----------------------+----------
     White |     1,702      1,850 |     3,552 
           |     87.82      86.73 |     87.25 
-----------+----------------------+----------
     Black |       201        249 |       450 
           |     10.37      11.67 |     11.05 
-----------+----------------------+----------
     Other |        35         34 |        69 
           |      1.81       1.59 |      1.69 
-----------+----------------------+----------
     Total |     1,938      2,133 |     4,071 
           |    100.00     100.00 |    100.00 

      Pearson chi2(2) =   1.9652   Pr = 0.374
```

The difference in the proportion of of white race who are male and female is 87.82 - 86.73 = 1.09 and I would like a confidence interval for this difference.

Comment: Take a look at my answer to a related question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/49877/7071

Answer (score 2):

The `prtest` command is what you need: `prtest sex, by(race)`. Your variables should not contain more than two groups.

```
webuse highschool
tab race sex, col chi2

// dummies
gen is_black = (race == 2) if race < 3
gen is_female = (sex == 2) if !mi(sex)

// proportions test
prtest is_female, by(is_black)
```

Comment: Thanks, the example I gave is not my actual application - the differences in my data are much larger that %. But it seems the `by` option is not allowed with `prop`

Comment: The mistake is mine -- I was referring to the `prtest` command, which operates like the `ttest` command but for proportions. I have rewritten my answer entirely.

Comment: Thanks again, but all my variables /do/ take on more than 2 levels so I get `XXX takes on 3 values, not 2`

Comment: Then you will need to recode your categorical variables to dummies (binary variables of true/false form). Use `tab` with the `gen` option: `tab race, gen(race_)` and then `prtest sex, by(race_1)` to test the gender gap.

Comment: Thanks, but when I try your suggestion (with the `highschool` data) I get `1.553333333333333 not in [0,1]`

Comment: Use the immediate of `-prtest-` instead, that is, `-prtesti-`

Comment: @P Sellaz: you need to encode the variables as pure 0/1 binaries for `prtest` to function. I have included a full working example based on your variables. The help page for `prtest` has more examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the immediate form of `-prtest-` instead, that is, `-prtesti-`.

The downside is that you have to input the counts and proportions manually:

With your example:

```
prtesti 1702 0.8782 1850 0.8673

Two-sample test of proportions                     x: Number of obs =     1702
                                                   y: Number of obs =     1850
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Variable |       Mean   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |      .8782   .0079276                      .8626622    .8937378
           y |      .8673   .0078874                       .851841     .882759
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        diff |      .0109   .0111829                     -.0110181    .0328181
             |  under Ho:   .0112015     0.97   0.331
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        diff = prop(x) - prop(y)                                  z =   0.9731
    Ho: diff = 0

    Ha: diff < 0                 Ha: diff != 0                 Ha: diff > 0
 Pr(Z < z) = 0.8347         Pr(|Z| < |z|) = 0.3305          Pr(Z > z) = 0.1653
```